# "A Stop Job is running for session 1 of user SeAL80s " in fedora 23 shutdown prosess

Tags: shutdown, systemd

My System is **Fedora 23 x86_64** running **Xfce4**

When system installed , i did:

```
su # root to open sudo 
sudo vi to disable selinux
sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/ to add extra fonts
sudo chmod 755 fonts folder
sudo chmod 644 fonts files
sudo mv to add mirror repos
```

and remove something i don't like with:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-core-libs tigervnc-server-minimal tigervnc-license libpinyin libpinyin-data libreport ibus-* firewall-config yum system-config-printer-libs xfce4-appfinder catfish xfce4-clipman-plugin seahorse xfburn orage geany evince-libs claws-mail claws-mail-* midori pidgin transmission-common asunder parole pragha libabiword gnumeric xfce4-dict gparted abrt-* gnome-abrt xfdashboard fedora-release-notes xfce4-about plymouth-core-lib xfce4-diskperf-plugin xfce4-verve-plugin xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-genmon-plugin xfce4-battery-plugin xfce4-cpugraph-plugin xfce4-eyes-plugin xfce4-systemload-plugin xfce4-screenshooter-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfce4-fsguard-plugin xfce4-netload-plugin xfce4-time-out-plugin xfce4-mount-plugin
sudo apt-get update
```

and shutdown (i don't recall if there is the bug appeared) but when i installed mariadb (or mysql) and postgresql and other things and shutdown there is always

```
"A Stop Job is running for session 1 of user SeAL80s "
```

Forums say it's a systemd bug but on systemctl command:

```
systemctl status mariadb.service -l
```

shows following info:

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-12-16 08:13:16 CST; 5min ago
 Main PID: 1107 (mysqld)
   Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─1107 /usr/sbin/mysqld
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621793179904 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621793179904 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621793179904 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621793179904 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1617005
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621044315904 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621793179904 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621793179904 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: 2015-12-16  8:13:16 139621793179904 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1107]: Version: '10.1.9-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
Dec 16 08:13:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
systemctl status postgresql -l shows 
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I don't thing it's mariadb or postgresql problem .

When shutdown, it only shows

```
"A Stop job is running..."
```

not saying what job.

How can i debug this nasty bug ?

What tools or information do i need?

Comment: Sorry for the mass , i obvious did something wrong . Can i keep the output format organized ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug. It affect me too. First time I've seen this bug on Fedora 20 or 21. It was patched, but returned in 23. It's somehow related to systemd and it's not only on Fedora - I've seen posts about it ex. on Arch Linux forums.

You can share with this, describing problems in this bug on bugzilla: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1088619 or https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1272635

Comment: Arch doesn't have this problem,or i can say systemd 228 doesn't have,Fedora's systemd is 222.